# System.TypeException - Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException

Tags: apex, exception

I have a Class exposed as service and is consuming the xml for Oppty with an external ID. Based on the extID, update operation is being done. Update operation is followed by exception handling.

From 2 weeks, getting the apex exception - System.TypeException: Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException.

From the code read-out, its due to the Opportunity update; but not much details available as its happening. Any clue to help debug is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This test illustrates a likely cause:

```
@isTest
private class ExceptionTest {
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        try {
            Integer i = 1 / 0;
            System.assert(false, 'Exception 1 expected');
         } catch (Exception e) {
             try {
                 Integer n = e.getNumDml();
                 System.assert(false, 'Exception 2 expected');
             } catch (TypeException ee) {
                 System.assertEquals(
                         'Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException',
                         ee.getMessage()
                         );
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Instead of this code causing a compilation error because the `getNumDml` method is only relevant to exceptions such as `DmlException`, a runtime error (a `TypeException`) is thrown when the method is called. Not a helpful design.

So look out in your code for cases where an `Exception` is caught but [methods only relevant to `DmlException`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) are invoked. The code will be fine if a `DmlException` is caught because that guarantees the correct exception type.