# System.TypeException: Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException

Tags: apex, class

I am trying to send an object(Account) as a parameter from my batch class, I am getting this exception.

> FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException

**Code:**

```
Account InsertAcc = New Account();
InsertAcc.Name='Test';
Insert InsertAcc;
//My method calling
classname.methodname(InsertAcc);
//class be like:
 @AuraEnabled
 public static Responseclass methodname(Account Accobject){

}
```

Comment: Do you have any try catch in your Class method?

Comment: yes I have but the same error is getting captured.

Comment: Please add that part of your code as well in the question?

Comment: where exactly exception thrown?

Comment: This is likely due to where you're sending the callout to this method from or the "context" it's sent in. Please post the code from your batch class and a bit more of the essence of your @AuraEnabled method.

Comment: After answering this I found a potential duplicate in [System.TypeException - Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/96690/102)

Answer (score 2):

The bug is likely in your Exception handling code.

The following message is indicating a method has been called on an instance of an Exception class that isn't applicable.

> FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Procedure is only valid for System.DmlException and System.MailException

You need to be careful with exceptions because Apex will compile code that probably doesn't make sense for the Type. E.g. The following with produce the same error as you are getting:

```
try {
    Integer divideByZero = 1 / 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.getDmlType(1);
}
```

The exception that gets thrown in this example is a MathException. The method `getDmlType(i)` isn't valid for it and apex will instead throw a TypeException if you aren't dealing with a DMLException or EmailException.

This can occur for the following [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm#dml_email_exception_methods):

1. `getDmlFieldNames(i)`
2. `getDmlFields(i)`
3. `getDmlId(i)`
4. `getDmlIndex(i)`
5. `getDmlMessage(i)`
6. `getDmlStatusCode(i)`
7. `getDmlType(i)`
8. `getNumDml()`

The line number of the `TypeException` should take you directly to the problem in the exception handling.